# Why using OPENSSL to decript a file it give "bad decrypt"

Tags: android, encryption, openssl

I tried to decrypt a file from [this](https://github.com/fs/android-base#updating-secret-keys) step

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -d -md sha256 -nosalt -a -pass pass:{KEY} -in secrets/keys.properties.crypted > temp
.properties
*** WARNING : deprecated key derivation used.
Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.
bad decrypt
32:error:06065064:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:bad decrypt:crypto\evp\evp_enc.c:570:
```

from the error message is recommended to use `Using -iter or -pbkdf2 would be better.` but instead of witch option

Answer (score 0):

Not instead of any other option, but in addition of the options given. PBKDF2 uses a hash function to derive a key from a password (it's a Password Based Key Derivation Function after all), using a high number of iterations and a salt.

So you can have `-d -md sha256 -nosalt -a` in addition to `-pbkdf2` *and* `-iter`, although preferably you should also use a salt, otherwise an adversary might use shortcuts to decrypting your ciphertext using rainbow tables or similar.

You can find more about PBKDF2 [in the standard](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8018). Note that OpenSSL doesn't necessarily perform the rest of the encryption or encryption format as described in that standard. OpenSSL often uses it's own proprietary algorithms and formats when it comes to simple command line encryption, even if the ciphers are compliant with standard definitions.

Of course during decryption you need to match the configuration options used to generate the ciphertext in the first place (as well as the passphrase of course). So the warning should be seen as separate from the error you get afterwards, and following the recommendation may not solve the "bad decrypt" error message.